# Using Akka HTTP parameters with dashes in their names

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I have some query parameters that have dashes in their names. When I attempt to write anything like

```
parameter('name-with-dash.as[String])
```

...it doesn't recognize anything after the first dash as being part of the parameter name.

Adding extra single quotes doesn't solve the problem:

```
parameter(''name-with-dash'.as[String])
```

Using double quotations around the `name-with-dashes` doesn't fix the problem either, I just get an `expected ')'` message where the `'` normally is at the front.

```
parameter('"name-with-dash".as[String])
```

If I ignore the single quote at the beginning, intellij doesn't show any errors but I get a compilation error that looks like this:

```
Error:(27, 17) type mismatch; found : String("Name-With-Dash")
required: ?{def as: ?} Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
 both method _string2NR in trait ToNameReceptacleEnhancements of type(string: String)akka.http.scaladsl.common.NameReceptacle[String]
 and method validateModel in object SomeObject of type (value: String)akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directive1[String]
 are possible conversion functions from String("Name-With-Dash") to ?{def as: ?}
      parameter("Name-With-Dash".as[String]).flatMap(p => provide[SomeIdentifier](SomeIdentifier(p))) |
```

FIXED:

This was fixed using the following form

`parameter("name-with-dash")`

ie. with only double quotes and no `.as[String]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple

```
parameter("name-with-dash".as[String])
```

works for me

Comment: In your error: `because they are ambiguous` try to check the trait you are mixins - otherwise, i dont know what the problem is

Comment: The issue was the `.as[String]`. I had an implicit converter in scope but it would work fine when there were no dashes. Using just the double quotes means you don't need to mark the `.as[String]` since it is already recognized as a string